# iPad orientation issue when device is in flat mode

Tags: ipad, orientation, landscape-portrait

Actually I develop one iPad application. It works fine as desired. But I have orientation issue when initially application launch. Actually i put iPad flat in landscape(Horizontal) style. Now every time when application launch it will open in portrait mode. I checked with supported orientation style and other things also. I put the log in ViewDidLoad for 3 orientation, 1) viewControllerOrientation - portrait 
2) ApplicationStatusbarOrientation -  portrait 
3) DeviceOrientation - Flat.

Now i have trouble even device is in flat mode (it really put like Horizontal) not in portrait, though why always it open in portrait mode.

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem. I tried using UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification. This worked fine when putting the iPad down. But when the user then touches buttons, the view is registered as portrait, even it was left in landscape orientation.